Android 10 sometimes not receiving calls
Since getting a new Hisense A7CC (colour Eink, android 10 and GiffGaff carrier in the UK) I noticed how sometimes while internet browsing there would be an error (the site cannot be reached, took too long to respond, ERR_TIMED_out) but didn't think of it too much as the page would load normally if I refreshed or even waited a few seconds for it to do it automatically.
Unfortunately I found a few weeks later that at random times the phone would not receive calls, with the other person calling getting sent straight to voicemail or just not reachable if I disabled the voicemail. If the person on the opposite end was to repeatedly try after about 3/4 times the call will get through, and from then on it will go through without issue.
Same issue with SMS: will not receive straight away, if I waited long enough the phone will start "syncing" and receive all the sent messages and future ones in real time with no delay. When that happens I think the mobile data also "awakens" and whatsapp starts syncing messages etc.
I know for sure that if I was to restart the connection to the cell by turning airplane mode on/off then the phone will be responsive for some time after that. For a while was thinking it had to do with it going into an extreme deep sleep and stopping "vital" functions, that doesn't seem to be the case as I would have the issue with the screen unlocked and using an app.
Is there an app or setting I can use to check the phone behaviour? or perhaps some other things to try just to get more details on what it could be? I have a separate work phone I could use for testing calls etc.
I really like the phone but this issue made me miss a few important calls.

Sounds to me like a problem with VoLTE/5G implementation on the phone (if it is supported by the MONO). What cellular connection types are provided by your GiffGaff plan? 2G/3G/4G/5G? Without VoLTE/5G the phone will fall back to the fastest mode below 4G for making or receiving calls. If this fallback fails you will be not available for calls.

I normally have 5G switched off to save battery. Giffgaff uses the O2 network and provides 3G to 5G, and I would normally have 4GLTE or 4G and 3G if I'm in a remote area. My settings at the moment are:
5G off,
5G NSA/SA mode off (only NSA, since today to try)
Preferred network (4G/3G/2G auto)
VoLTE disabled
What is MONO?
I normally use Network Cell Info lite to see stats regarding the connection

Disabling VoLTE is not a good idea, it is the only way to make calls on 4G/5G. According to what I have read O2 has shut down it's 3G network in UK in 2021. Therefore when you make or receive calls the phone would have to switch to 2G/EDGE connection without VoLTE.

ok I just tried reactivating it. Though I wouldn't see how that would affect sms or data?

SMS should work as normal via VoLTE and the for the data the cellular should open a separate data connection so that this is not charged on your data plan. Only in certain roaming scenarios VoLTE may create some minor data traffic (very few KB a day).
